I don't get to choose which of the firebase dependencies to use in Xcode

I want to only add Authentication and Messaging, but I don't know how, in some youtube videos I get a checkbox in the start of every row but I don't see it here. When I choose none though and get the package product out of the screen, it automatically returns to its default state.

See the right-most column (it looks empty, but each row has chevrons pointing away from each other) - what happens if you click on that?

Actually you can choose which one you want to add on columns. Try to select None.

If you want to add specific  frameworks you can try by using CocoaPods.
CocoaPods install: How to install firebase pods for Specifically to Swift 3.0
